# How to access a property of one class from another class?

Tags: ios, class, swift, properties, subclass

I have one class:

```
class FoodListTable: UITableViewController
```

At the end of this class, I have a variable of the sum of numbers in an array:

```
var calorieTotal: Int {
    return calorieNumberArray.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
}
```

I also have another class:

```
class Menu: Calculator { // Calculator is a class I had created earlier
```

In this class, I want to have a property that is the `var calorieTotal: Int` from `class FoodListTable: UITableViewController`. I have started this property:

```
let dividend =
```

How can I access the 'calorieTotal' property from the first class? I am very new to programming so please provide all the code possible. If you were wondering, I have looked for this question, but I still can't seem to figure it out?

Comment: Your Menu would need to have a reference to the FoodListTable object to access a property on it. In what context will the Menu object need the calorie total? If the Menu is being used in your FoodListTable, you might just want to pass in the calorieTotal value when the FoodListTable calls a function on the Menu.

Comment: The menu isn't being used in the FoodListTable, the classes are separate. If there is any more information you need to know just let me know. @rikkigibson